# MVC 4 Redirecting from an Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an **ExceptionHandlerAttribute** which is applied universally.

When an security exception occurrs I am trying to redirect to a page, but also have the URL change too. When a child action or other sub action has an error, it merges the error html page with the current page:

```
var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
var result = new ViewResult {
                   ViewName = viewName,
                   ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
               };
result.ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
return result;
```

How can I get it to rediectly completely to the Account/Login or the Error/Security etc and not merge the pages as attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:

First define an action filter that derives from AuthorizeAttribute. When this attribute detects that the user is not authenticated AND it is an ajax request, it returns a 403 status (mvc does weird stuff with 401s).  If it isn't ajax, do the normal stuff that AuthorizeAttribute does.

Next, in your layout file(s), set a global global error handler (assuming you are using jquery) that looks for 403 status and if it finds it calls location.replace on your logout url.

I am assuming this problem is happening in ajax calls.